# .htaccess too many redirections error trying to redirect based on HTTP_HOST

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-2.4, redirect, apache2

I have two different domains pointing to my server.

One of them I use it to redirect to my portfolio webpage. So, if I access through the second domain, I would like to be redirected to a different folder on my Apache server.

I've tried various solutions, but I always end with a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. These are the two last solutions I've tried:

```
RewriteEngine On

Options -Indexes

# My first try, using IF statement
#<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'hugonavarropadreyhermano.com' && %{REQUEST_URI} != 'benvingut'">
#       RewriteRule ^ http://hugonavarropadreyhermano.com/benvingut [L]
#</If>

# My second try, using RewriteCond
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} hugonavarropadreyhermano.com$
#RewriteRule ^ http://hugonavarropadreyhermano.com/benvingut [L]

# Actual redirect for the main domain
RedirectMatch ^/$ /welcome/
RedirectMatch ^/index\.html(.*) /welcome/index.html$1
```

Resuming, if I access to http://hugonavarropadreyhermano.com I'd like to be redirected to "http://hugonavarropadreyhermano.com/benvingut"

Answer (score 0):

Your rewritecond is a string comprison, the $ was too much

```
# My second try, using RewriteCond
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} hugonavarropadreyhermano.com
RewriteRule ^ http://hugonavarropadreyhermano.com/benvingut [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution wasn't to apply different rewrite rules, but to use VirtualHosts as specified in the Apache documentation([enter link description here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)):

> Your server has multiple hostnames that resolve to a single address, and you want to respond differently for www.example.com and www.example.org.

It was as easy as following these instructions:

- [Create New Virtual Host Files](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts#step-four-%E2%80%94-create-new-virtual-host-files)